# Saltstack formula for installing a package using a remote tarball with checksum

Tags: python, salt-stack

How does one install a package from a tar ball using salt stack? For example, I want to install Apache Tomcat from a remote tar ball - how can I achieve this? I tried using file.managed, but it's showing mismatch in source_hash - how can I predict checksum dynamically using the source url?

```
{% set tomcat = pillar.get('tomcat', {}) -%}
{% set version = tomcat.get('version', 'x.x.x') -%}
{% set tomcat_package = source + '/tomact-' + version + '.tar.gz' -%}
  file.managed:
    - name: {{ tomcat_package }}
    - source: http://tomcat.org/download/tomcat-{{ version }}.tar.gz
    - source_hash: {{ checksum }}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the package management state instead? (also typo on line 3) http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html

Comment: i am trying to extract hadoop installation package. It wont be available in package.

Answer (score 3):

[`file.managed`](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html) only download that file for you. To extract it, take a look at the [`archive.extracted`](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.archive.html#module-salt.states.archive):

```yaml
tomcat:
  archive:
    - extracted
    - name: /opt/
    - source: http://mirrors.digipower.vn/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.47/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz
    - source_hash: md5=efbae77efad579b655ae175754cad3df
    - archive_format: tar
    - options: z
    - if_missing: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
```

Comment: i am getting an error when i run the above code:  Comment:  ```State archive.extracted found in sls hadoop.core is unavailable```